Movie about a village of evil witches
Young couple (wife is pregnant) goes to live in a village which turns out to be a coven of witches.  Husband is recruited; the coven wants the baby and he helps them try to kill her and take the baby. She survives and he is killed. Final scene shows her in a park with the baby, and a young horse-mounted policeman helps her with the baby carriage. We realize he is also a witch because of the way he ties a knot -the witches all tie things with a special knot. Seen on tv in the early seventies.

Rosemary's Baby?

I loved Rosemary's Baby, and have seen it several times. The idea of the satanists who want the unborn child, and of the husband becoming complicit with the villains, is similar, but that isn't the movie. Thanks for the contribution, though!

This is Crowhaven Farm from 1970. From the IMDb synopsis:

An aura of mystery and tales of supernatural activity surrounds Crowhaven Farm,when it comes into the possession of Ben and Maggie Porter,a couple moving to the farm to try for a chance to save their troubled marriage. Maggie,immediately senses that all is not right,and that perhaps the farm's reputation for being haunted by restless spirits and being the home of an ancient coven of witches is true.

Maggie discovers she's pregnant at some point, and the witches are after her baby. The movie is available in 5 parts on Youtube and in part 5 (around 12:30) you can see the final scene you've mentioned where the horse-mounted cop ties a knot on her baby's carriage in a park:




That is absolutely correct, Walt! I'm impressed. And I am also impressed by the cast; as a little girl I had no idea that it starred Hope Lange and one of the Carradines.

Wow, it was much scarier when I was seven.  And she wasn't betrayed by her husband - she actually betrayed him to save herself from being pressed to death. I remember thinking that Ben sure was reincarnated quickly, to turn up in the body of a grown man so soon after his death!
